# All subsets of collinear points - Prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking, points

I am trying to make a backtracking program in Prolog to determine all subsets of collinear points. 
The problem:  Are given n points in a plan (represented using its coordinates).
Write a predicate to determine all subsets of collinear points.

Example :

Input: [ [1,1] , [2,2] , [3,3] , [0,0] , [4,8], [1,2], [6,7] , [8,9] , [10,11] ]

Output: [ [  [1,1] , [2,2] , [3,3] ]  , [ [1,1] , [2,2], [0,0] ] , [ [2,2], [3,3], [0,0] ] , [ [1,1] , [3,3], [0,0] ] , ...]

So far I thaught at checking if 3 points are collinear by checking this formula :
 `(Xc - Xa)/ (Xb - Xa) = (Yc - Ya)/ (Yb - Ya).`

But, I don't think this will work because I need to solve the problem using backtracking. I should take one candidate at each function call to see if it matches with the rest .

Could you suggest me a proper way of checking if 3 points are collinear?

Comment: What you describe isn't clear at all! You should give at least a simple example of input and expected output... From what I understood If you have a list of points you could recursively check them in group of 3 to see if they are collinear and as base case the last 3 points....

Comment: @coder , I put here the example . Sorry for that , I totally forgot. And yes, I need to recursively find all subsets of 3 points which are collinear.

Comment: that input doesn't make sense as a prolog starting query ... but in general you have the right idea. Three points a,b,c are colinear if the slope of a,b, and b,c is the same (but for any order of inputs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your program query will be something like:

```
?- findColinears([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[0,0],[4,8],[1,2],[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], Out).
```

Obviously I won't provide code to solve the whole problem for you, but in general a top-down approach could involve predicates like the following:

```
colinear( P1, P2, P3 ) :- slope( P1, P2, S ), slope( P1, P3, S ).
colinear( P1, P2, P3 ) :- slope( P1, P2, S ), slope( P2, P3, S ).
colinear( P1, P2, P3 ) :- slope( P1, P3, S ), slope( P2, P3, S ).

slope( P1, P2, S ) :-
  P1 = p( X1, Y1 ),
  P2 = p( X2, Y2 ),
  S is ((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)).

findColinearTriplet( ListOfPoints, Triplet ) :-
  member( P1, ListOfPoints ),
  member( P2, ListOfPoints ), dif(P1, P2),
  member( P3, ListOfPoints ), dif(P1, P3), dif(P2, P3),
  colinear(P1, P2, P3),
  Triplet = [P1, P2, P3].
```

You could then use these to find all possible `Triplet` unifications.
Of course, some triplets are equivalent (e.g. `[p(1,1), p(2,2), p(3,3)]` and `[p(3,3), p(1,1), p(2,2)]`). Also, some will be repeated. If you want unique triplets, you'll have to manually build such a unique list from all non-unique triplets collected.

Your final `findColinears` predicate for instance, might look something like:

```
findColinears( ListOfPairs, Out ) :-
  convertToPoints( ListOfPairs, ListOfPts ),
  findall( Triplet, findColinearTriplet(ListOfPts, Triplet), ListOfTriplets),
  discardDuplicates( ListOfTriplets, Out ).
```

for appropriately defined `convertToPoints` and `discardDuplicates` predicates.

Comment: - Cu placere :)